# Configuring force parameters in D3 so that all layers run in ellipsis (circles) with one central node

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, data-visualization, force-layout

Me and my developer are trying to get the force parameters right as to create this awesome visualisation, but we are having a hard time.

The visualisation should look like this:

[image: Desired]

But it currently looks like this:

[image: Status quo]

Do you guys have some ideas on how we can solve this?

We are currently using these parameters, with the grey node being the central node:

```
.force('collide', d3.forceCollide().strength(1).radius((d: any) => {
if (d.labels[0] === "Basis") {
return 80;
} else if (d.labels[0] === "Thema") {
return 70;
} else if (d.labels[0] === "Onderneming") {
return 70;
} else {
return options.nodeRadius * 1.3;
}
}))
var linkForce = d3.forceLink(relationships).id((d: any) => d.id).distance((d: any) => {
if (d.type === "WERKT_AAN") {
return 120;
} else if (d.type === "DRAAGT_BIJ_AAN") {
return 100;
} else if (d.type === "DRAAGT_BIJ_MET") {
return 90;
} else {
return 90;
}
}
).iterations(2);
simulation.force('link', linkForce);
```

and anchor central node to center of the screen

Comment: Is your data a tree (are there are no loops?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708570/graph-layout-algorithm-of-neo4j

Comment: @AndrewReid, yes it is a tree, no loops. Why? Are there any presets for this?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, thank you, we are familiar with the documentation, but can't figure out why the graph isn't doing the thing we have in mind.